# Remove all borders and tab bars from Yakuake?

Tags: command-line, kde, kubuntu, konsole

[image]

machine: kubuntu 11.04x64 w/ kde4

- the top terminal is of Yakuake w/ "No Border" option already enabled
- the bottom is of Konsole w/ "No Border" option also enabled

how do I remove all borders from Yakuake to make it resemble Konsole at the bottom so as only the transparent terminal portion is visible?

if not possible what is a better replacement to Yakuake that has true no border settings, as well allows drag/drop of texts into the terminal?  Already tried Tilda but it doesn't allow you to drag and drop texts into the terminal; tried Guake but can't get it to work in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-this is one workaround to the large tabbar at bottom of yakuake window"

[One Pixel Title](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/One+Pixel+Title?content=142441): A clean interface but for the one pixel line at the bottom of the window.[image]